# How to create delegate/nested async context manager for aiohttp?

Tags: python-3.5, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to create custom request manager for crawler with dynamic waiting.
My crawler need to make requests to sites which prohibit parallel requests from same ip address. If such blocking occurs requests returns with HTTP error codes 403, 503, 429, etc.
In case of error I want to wait some time and repeat request. But for simplicity of parsers they just call get and receive correct page.
I want to use **aiohttp** and new **async with** syntax of **Python 3.5** so my parsers classes can use **async with** for my **requester** class same way if they used **aiohttp.ClientSession** like this:

```
# somewhere in a parser
async def get_page(self, requester, page_index):
  async with requester.get(URL_FMT.format(page_index)) as response:
    html_content = await response.read()
    result = self.parsing_page(html_content)
    return result
```

if **requester** is **aiohttp.ClientSession**, then **response** is **aiohtpp.ClientResponse** which have **__aenter__** and **__aexit__** methods, so **async with** working as expected.
But if I put my **requester** class in the middle it is not working anymore.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/project/api/tornado_runner.py", line 6, in <module>
    from api import app
  File "/opt/project/api/api.py", line 20, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(session.login())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 337, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/opt/project/api/viudata/session.py", line 72, in login
    async with self.get('https://www.viudata.com') as resp:
AttributeError: __aexit__
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f44f61ef240>
```

It is looking like this.

```
class Requester:
   def __init__(self, session: aiohttp.ClientSession):
     self.session = session

   async def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
     is_result_successful = False
     while not is_result_successful:
       response = await self.session.get(*args, **kwargs)
       if response.status in [503, 403, 429]:
          await self.wait_some_time()
       else:
          is_result_successful = True
     return response
```

From my understanding **self.session.get** is coroutine function so I will **await** it. Result is **aiohttp.ClientResponse** which have **__aenter__** or **__aexit__**. But if return it **parser**'s code of **async with** block return odd error.

Can you say what I need to replace to with my **requester** class as with **aiohttp.ClientSession**?

Comment: Could you expand on *"it is not working anymore"* with a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

You should write additional code to support `async with` protocol.

See [client.request()](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/client.py#L94) and [_RequestContextManager](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/client.py#L552) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks you for point me where I need to start from. But it is very sad that new syntax sugar create more problems than it solves. Especially for implementing simple decorator.

Comment: Regular python function is not and context manager too, you need to do some tricks to make it work as both function and context manager.